# CFToken / CFID in Coldfusion 11

Tags: cookies, coldfusion

CF11 is prepending the values of these cookies with what looks to be a hash of the application name.

In CF9, the value of CFID for me is along the lines of: 2219
In CF11, this changes to be Z3ir0kan93jawdd3kz38onobced8tfgn2kc3fy8i0w884gqffsn-2219

I need to be able to run a CF9 and CF11 server in the same pool (while we do the upgrade), but the differences in the cookie values mean that if you log in on a CF9 server and navigate to a CF11 server, you'll get logged out.

Is there any way to get CF11 to use the CF9 format for these cookie values?

Comment: Can you switch to using JSESSIONIDs instead?

Comment: Possibly, but that might mean killing user's sessions when we switch to it.

Answer (score 2):

The value of CFID/CFTOKEN was changed from a simple numeric value to a string+numeric for security reasons.

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/predictable-cookie-session-ids-reported.html

> **Reason**
>
> In its default configuration, Adobe ColdFusion uses a pair of cookies named CF_ID and CF_TOKEN to manage user sessions. These two cookies are only ever used in tandem with each other--they are never used separately.
>
> Even though CF_ID is sequential, CF_TOKEN is random and is unpredictable. Since it is the combination of both cookies that is used, the resulting combination is also unpredictable.
>
> **Solution**
>
> To eliminate this error in your compliance testing, you can configure ColdFusion to use J2EE session identifiers instead of CF_ID and CF_TOKEN.
>
> **Note:** This solution does not make your ColdFusion server any more or less secure.

So it's not in your best interest to have CF 11 use the old-style numeric CF_ID value.

If you're going to have CF 9 and CF 11 in the same pool, where requests can randomly bounce from one to the other, you'll run into a number of other problems. I spent the better part of a year converting from CF 8 to CF 9 about two years ago (yes, yes, I know).

For instance, if you happen to use any CF UI components, you'll have problems when a request that starts on CF X rendered HTML & JS goes to CF Y, which has updated JS functions for that feature. We ripped them all out and converted to jQuery/jQuery UI

We also ran into something as simple as this:

`this.name = HASH(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()));`

`getDirectoryFromPath()` returned an upper-case value in 8 and lower-case value in 9 (or vice-versa). We had to update it to this:

`this.name = HASH(Lcase(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())));`

in order to have them use the same application name and, therefore, session.

You'll be better off running CF 11 in its own pool and running a full regression test against it to figure out what needs to be updated.

Comment: Not sure how it changing to string+numeric helps security, as the string will never change. Changing to use jsession for the sake of PCI isn't all that appealing either. What I'm after is a way to get CF11 handle the cookies in the same way as CF9. If that can't be done, then so be it.